# Increase by one, Shortest path, changes the edges or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, trees

as i read the following text :

"Let P be a shortest path from some vertex s to some other vertex t in a graph. If the
weight of each edge in the graph is increased by one, P will still be a shortest path
from s to t"

> Solution: False. the shortest path would change if 1 was added to every edge weight.

I ran into a new question:

> Suppose we have a Graph G in which weight of all edges is >1 (positive). If we increase weight of all edges by one, the shortest path between two specific vertex has the same edges.

I doubt about this question. would u please anyone clarify me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be the complete graph on three vertices $A,B,$ and $C$. Let edges $AB$ and $BC$ have weight $2$, and edge $AC$ have weight $4.5$.

Then the shortest path from $A$ to $C$ is via $B$. But if you increase the weights to $3,3,$ and $5.5$, the shortest path is the edge $AC$.

If you want integer weights, you can do it with four points, with edge weights $AB=BC=CD=2$, $AD=7$.

Comment: Dear @tonyK, what about min-cut in such graph? this is unchanged or after increasing this is change, too?

Comment: For these particular graphs, the minimum cuts are unchanged. You will need a more complicated graph. If you can't think of one yourself, perhaps you might post a new question.

Comment: Dear @TonyK, i ask it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021632/increase-by-one-all-edges-min-cut-changes-or-not

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

A path with less edges has its weight increase less under the add-1-to-each-edge scenario than a path with more edges.  So a path with initially higher weight could be surpassed by a lower weight path with more edges.

Comment: with your hint, i conclude that the above sentence is false?

Comment: I would agree with that.  I think you could find a fairly simple example using a graph that consists of a single cycle.