# Increase by one all edges, Min-Cut, changes or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, trees

My Friends,

as i ask a new question recently,

[Increase by one, Shortest path, changes the edges or not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021517/increase-by-one-shortest-path-changes-the-edges-or-not)

i want to ask a related question as a new post

> Suppose we have a Graph G in which weight of all edges is >1
>   (integer and positive). If we increase weight of all edges by one, the min-cut (S,
>   T) in two graphs remain unchanged.

i want to find an formal way to proof why the min cut dosnt change.

Comment: The min-cut can certainly change.

Comment: Dear @TonyK, i thinking....

Answer (score 2):

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

[image]

Comment: @MJD: See [min-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut). Initially, min-cut cost is $2+2=4$ (which is less than $4.5$); after change, min-cut cost is $5.5$ (which is less than $3+3=6$).

Comment: Dear @TonyK, if edge be integer...? i'm sorry. i edit my question...

Comment: @user153695: Then you need a bigger graph. But I've constructed enough counter-examples for you today.